# redirect to next page if only check box is unchecked

Tags: php, html, ajax, checkbox

i have html table also i have button when click the button redirect to the next page and show the values regarding to the passed data but i want if any check box in the table checked it will not redirect to the nextpage it only redirect when all the check box in table unchecked,i tried but its not working can any one guide me.

**ajax**

```
    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#redirect").click(function() {

        var chkBox=document.getElementById("checkAddress").value;


        if (chkBox.checked == 0)
        {

     var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;

        $.blockUI(

       { 

         message: '<h2>Please wait...</h2><img src="/image/loader.gif" />',
     timeout: 2000

       }); 


    $.ajax({
            type:"post",

        data:"clientid="+clientid,
        success:function(data){

                         window.location = '?action=redirectclientpricenotification&clientid='+clientid+'';
                          $("#result").html(data);
                         $('.blockUI').hide();
        }
    }); 
        }

        else{

             alert("chkBox");

        }

    });
});

</script>
```

**html**

```
<th ><img  id='redirect'  src="/image/exporttt.png"  style="margin:-30 0 0 0px;cursor:pointer;"  >
</th>

<td id="CPH_GridView1_Status1'.$rows['net_id'].'" class="updateseleniumroute status1 '.$rows["net_id"].' "><input type="checkbox" style="margin:0 0 0 93px;" id="checkAddress" name="checkAddress" '.$checked_value.' ></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#redirect").click(function() {

        var chkBox=$("#checkAddress");


        if (chkBox.attr('checked') != 'checked')
        {

     var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;

        $.blockUI(

       { 

         message: '<h2>Please wait...</h2><img src="/image/loader.gif" />',
     timeout: 2000

       }); 


    $.ajax({
            type:"post",

        data:"clientid="+clientid,
        success:function(data){

                         window.location = '?action=redirectclientpricenotification&clientid='+clientid+'';
                          $("#result").html(data);
                         $('.blockUI').hide();
        }
    }); 
        }

        else{

             alert("chkBox");

        }

    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes:

```
var chkBox=document.getElementById("checkAddress");
```

Donot append the .value , that is required only if you want the value. If the rest of the code is fine this should do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var chkBox=document.getElementById("checkAddress");
console.log(chkBox.checked);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with less variables:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#redirect").click(function () {
            if (document.getElementById("checkAddress").checked) {
                $.blockUI({
                        message: '<h2>Please wait...<img src="/image/loader.gif" /></h2>',
                        timeout: 2000
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    data: "clientid=" + document.getElementById("client").value,
                    success: function (data) {
                        window.location = '?action=redirectclientpricenotification&clientid=' + document.getElementById("client").value + '';
                        $("#result").html(data);
                        $('.blockUI').hide();
                    }
                });
            } else {

                alert("chkBox");

            }

        });
    });
</script>
```